# Rails API cache endpoint with Carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I'm experiencing some issues when caching some data in my Rails API, when the model has a Carrierwave uploader attached. The issue started when I added versions in my ImageUploader.

The model looks like this:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :title, :intro, :body, :image, :release_date, :slug

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

The ImageUploader now looks like this:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  process resize_to_fit: [1920,1080]
  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [400,400]
  end
  version :big do
    process resize_to_fill: [1080,1080]
  end
```

Before the change I had no versions, and did no processing the original image.

I have tried caching this endpoint, which looks like this:

```
today = Date.today
data = Rails.cache.fetch("articles_#{params[:slug]}", :expires_in => 12.hours) do
  Article
    .includes(:related_articles, :users, :external_authors, :categories)
    .where('release_date <= ?', today)
    .where(slug: params[:slug])
    .first
    .as_json(include: [{ related_articles: { except: [:body, :intro, :preview] } }, { categories: { } }, { users: { except: [:password_digest, :password_reset_token, :password_reset_sent_at] } }, { external_authors: { } }])
end

render json: data, status: :ok
```

The problem is that it initally works, then it suddenly does not work. Especially it does not work after restarting the server (but it has sometimes stopped working randomly after multiple fetches where it worked being cached), giving me error like the following: `uninitialized constant ImageUploader::Uploader2293312720`

If I then change the cacheKey, it works again, but suddenly the error comes back, either randomly (it works multiple times before it randomly gives me the error), or when restarting server.

For now, I've just removed the caching, and it works fine with no issues.

I'm using: Rails v`5.2.5`, and Carrierwave v`2.2.2`.

Comment: Have you tried caching the result of calling `to_json` instead of `as_json`? `as_json` returns a hash that may be including ruby classes that have to be serialized and then deserialized, if you store the result of `to_json`, it's just a string, which should even make things faster since you will cache that part too

Comment: @arieljuod This seems to have fixed the issue! Thanks!